# Store new JSON data to existing file in python

Tags: python, json

I've been looking around the web and I cannot find a way on adding new JSON data to array.

**Example: I would like to add player_two, player_three through python.**

```
{
  "players": {
    "player_one": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": "0",
      "email": "bob@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve doing this through python?

What I've tried:

```
with open("/var/www/html/api/toons/details.json", 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(avatarDetails, outfile)
```

Comment: Did you try something? What's the error that you got?

Comment: I have only tried json.dumps but that does nothing.

Comment: Load the existing JSON into a Python dictionary and then mutate that as needed and save when complete.

Comment: What do you mean about *that does nothing* ? Any way, please edit your question and add the code that you have tried, however SO is not a code write service.

Comment: @KevinGuan it doesn't insert it into the json file, it just updates it.

Comment: @brownzilla Thanks, wait me post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example, read the file as a dict, update the dict, then use `json.dumps()` to get the json data:

```
import json

# open your jsonfile in read mode
with open('jsonfile') as f:
    # read the data as a dict use json.load()
    jsondata = json.load(f)

# add a new item into the dict
jsondata['players']['player_two'] = {'email': 'kevin@example.com', 'name': 'Kevin', 'age': '0'}

# open that file in write mode
with open('jsonfile', 'w') as f:
    # write the data into that file
    json.dump(jsondata, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Now the file looks like:

```
{
    "players": {
        "player_one": {
            "age": "0",
            "email": "bob@example.com",
            "name": "Bob"
        },
        "player_two": {
            "age": "0",
            "email": "kevin@example.com",
            "name": "Kevin"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `json.load(f)` and `json.dump(data, f, ...)` would be better than `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()` which require explicit file reads and writes.

Comment: Is there a way to take a json response and then insert that in the existing 'player' array?

Comment: @brownzilla Well, what does *json response* mean?

Comment: So I have setup an RPC system which will return JSON response e.g `{"name": "brownzilla", "hp": "15","species":"dog"}`. How can I get that response and insert that into my existing `players` array?

Comment: Oh, understand. So like I did in my answer, `jsondata['players']['player_number'] = JSON_response`?

Comment: Okay so scrap that. I want to insert it into the iterate JSON object, e.g `"players": [ ]` How can I do that?

Comment: So easy! Just `jsondata['players'].append(JSON_response)`.

Comment: and JSON_response being the response I get from my RPC system? e.g. `{"name": "brownzilla", "hp": "15","species":"dog"}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your file contains this JSON:

```
{
  "players": {
    "player_one": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": "0",
      "email": "bob@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

You can parse the data into a Python dictionary using `json.load()`:

```
with open('/var/www/html/api/toons/details.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Add your new players:

```
data['players']['player_two'] = dict(name='Bobbie', age=100, email='b@blah.com')
data['players']['player_three'] = dict(name='Robert', age=22, email='robert@blah.com')
```

Then save it back to a file:

```
with open('/var/www/html/api/toons/details.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```